# Reshape of items in listview

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

What i am trying to achieve is to reshape the listview of the leas/accounts/etc...
To be shown as grid view.

For example, what i want to see is something like this

[image]
Instead of this...
[image]

Please advise,

Darko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd be doing is putting the listview into a custom table with borders. That could be done using a jQuery plug-in called [DataTables](http://datatables.net/), JavaScript, standard HTML with repeats or Apex Tables. I wouldn't necessarily recommend doing what you propose in general, but am simply responding to your question since you've asked it. You could easily break something that's already known to work very well. If you attempt this, make certain you test, test and then test a whole lot more before implementing it.

Also, I recommend you consider the impact this might have on Salesforce 1. Finally, there's something on  the App Exchange called [Grid Buddy Unlimited](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IkInEAK) that is similar to what you're asking about, but not quite as visually stimulating. However, it definitely is SF1 compatible, but it's also $10/seat.

**Edit**

If you're not interested in demoing one of the App Exchange options, I suggest you first look at the link I've provided to the Data Tables plug-in or else try writing some code and post it, after which I'll be happy to take a look at it. If you need the existing code for a standard page to help you get started, you'll want to install [Layout Page](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZkUEAU) from the App Exchange which will convert most any standard page to visual force for you. Essentially you're looking at wrapping everything that's inside the listview in a table as below:

```
<table>
<thead> probably want any buttons and index in this section
</thead>
<tr>
<th>Action</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>State/Province</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Lead Status</th>
<th>Owner Alias</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Action Edit|Del +symbol (may want to separate into three cells here and would need to do a column span = 3 if you do in Action of th above</th>
<th>Name of lead1</th>
<th>State/Province for lead1</th>
<th>Phone for lead1</th>
<th>Email for lead1</th>
<th>Lead1 Status</th>
<th>Owner Alias for lead1</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

That's the general concept only you'd use repeats coming from your controller.

Comment: Skuid is another option that you can look into http://www.skuidify.com/

Comment: @crmprogdev can you please provide me with 1 example of how an i do it for at least one, or something close to that? It will mean the world to me. Thanks

Comment: See my edit above